# iOS Bluetooth Background process not working on time

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, core-bluetooth

I am trying to send data on my bluetooth device using app when it is on background mode. It is communicate to the device successfully but not on time. If I want the background process start after 2 minutes, but It starts after 10 minutes.

Here is my code. And I want to start the background process task after 2 minutes.

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        print(minutes)
        print("Scene enter background")
        if MotorControl.motorWorkItem != nil{
            scheduleAppRefresh()
        }
    }

    func scheduleAppRefresh() {

       let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.apple-samplecode.ColorFeed.refresh")
       request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2 * 60)
       do {
          try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
       } catch {
          print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
       }
    }
```

SessionManager.runningSeriesIndex = 0

```
            MotorControl.motorWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {

                print(SessionManager.runningSeriesIndex)

                print(SessionManager.tempoSeriesData[SessionManager.runningSeriesIndex])

                motor.setSpeedAndTimer(motorSpeedTimer: MotorSpeedTimer(speed: Int(SessionManager.tempoSeriesData[SessionManager.runningSeriesIndex]), timer: (2), timeNow: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)))

                if SessionManager.runningSeriesIndex < 8{

                    SessionManager.runningSeriesIndex += 1

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {

                            self.scheduleAppRefresh()

                        }

                        else{

                            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(60), execute: MotorControl.motorWorkItem!)

                        }

                    }

                    

                }

                

            }

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async(execute: MotorControl.motorWorkItem!)
```

Comment: That's not how background tasks work. You cannot schedule them for a specific time. You request the `earliestBeginDate`; your task will not start *before* this date, but that doesn't mean it will start *at* that date. It may run *after* that date, as determined by the operating system based on things like the battery/charging state, the device lock state, what else the device is doing, how much background execution your app has already performed etc

Comment: @Paulw11 Is any way to set it for specific time for background task?

Comment: No. iOS does not have any facility for an app to execute code at a specific time in the background